# putImageData of only portion of image data object

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an ImageData object which holds the screenshot of all monitors, so it is one huge ImageData. I want to now draw one monitor per time. I have all the monitor dimensions.

So I'm trying to use `ctx.putImageData(myImgDat, topLeftMonX, topLeftMonY, monWidth, monHeight)` but its not working, I dont think I understand the dirty concept so well as seen in docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#Understanding_putImageData

Is it possible to draw portion of imgaedata to canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, it doesn't work on your code is because your arugments passed is not met the format of the function.

As [MDN CanvasRenderingContext2D.putImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData#Understanding_putImageData) describes, it accepts `3` or `7` arguments, you have to pass either `3` or `7`, otherwise, in your example, `monWidth` and `monHeight` will be used as `dirtyX` and `dirtyY` instead of `dirtyWidth` and `dirtyHeighy`. You code would probably do

1. Copy the `rect(monWidth, monHeight, IMAGEDATA_WIDTH, IMAGEDATA_HEIGHT)`.
2. Put it on canvas's `rect(topLeftMonX + monWidth, topLeftMonY + monHeight, IMAGEDATA_WIDTH, IMAGEDATA_HEIGHT)`.

So, and it's somehow not very straight to put the target region to `(0,0)` of the target canvas, to achieve by your give condition, you may have to do:

1. First move imageData's `(0,0)` to target canvas's `(-topLeftMonX,
   -topLeftMonY)`.
2. Then start to put imageData at imageData's `(topLeftMonX, topLeftMonY)` which now is at the position `(0, 0)` of canvas.
3. The rectangle size will be `topLeftMonX x topLeftMonY`.

```js
ctx.putImageData(myImgDat,-topLeftMonX, -topLeftMonY, topLeftMonX, topLeftMonY, monWidth, monHeight);
```

Code above will copy the `rect(topLeftMonX, topLeftMonY, monWidth, monHeight)` on `myImgDat` to: `rect(0, 0, monWidth, monHeight)` on canvas.

You can take a look at how it works from the snippet below.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('bigCanvas')
        ,ctx  = canvas.getContext('2d');

var tcanvas = document.getElementById('testCanvas')
        ,tctx  = tcanvas.getContext('2d');

var grd = tctx.createRadialGradient(150, 100, 10, 150, 110, 150);
grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd.addColorStop(0.15, "blue");
grd.addColorStop(0.3, "cyan");
grd.addColorStop(0.5, "green");
grd.addColorStop(0.7, "yellow");
grd.addColorStop(0.85, "orange");
grd.addColorStop(1, "red");

tctx.fillStyle = grd;
tctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 200);

var imageData = tctx.getImageData(0, 0, 300, 200);
// Move imagedata's origin to (-150, -100) on canvas, 
// start to put data on canvas at imgae data's (150, 100)  and size is 150x100
// => copy rect(150,  100, 150, 100) to canvas' s rect (0,  0, 150, 100)
ctx.putImageData(imageData, -150, -100,  150, 100, 150, 100);

// Move imagedata's origin to (150, 100) on canvas, 
//start to put data on canvas at imgae data's (0, 0)  and and size is 150x100
// => copy rect(0, 0, 150, 100) to canvas' s rect (150,  100, 150, 100)
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 150, 100,  0, 0, 150, 100);

// Move imagedata's origin to (150, -100) on canvas,
// start to put data on canvas at imgae data's (0, 100)  and size is 150x100
// => copy rect(0, 100, 150, 100) to canvas' s rect (150, 0, 150, 100)
ctx.putImageData(imageData, 150, -100,  0, 100, 150, 100);

// Move imagedata's origin to (-150, 100) on canvas,
// start to put data on canvas at imgae data's (200, 0)  and size is 100x100
// => copy rect(200, 0, 150, 100) to canvas' s rect (50, 100, 150, 100)
ctx.putImageData(imageData, -150, 100,  200, 0, 100, 100);
```

```html
<div>Canvas for put ImageData:</div>
<canvas id="bigCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
<hr/>
<div>Canvas for get ImageData:</div>
<canvas id="testCanvas" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution:

```
            var iref = imagedata.data;

            // start - because took a single screenshot of alllll put togather, lets portion out the imagedata
            console.time('portion out image data');
            for (var i=0; i<collMonInfos.length; i++) {
                var screenUseW = collMonInfos[i].w;
                var screenUseH = collMonInfos[i].h;

                var screnImagedata = new ImageData(screenUseW, screenUseH);
                var siref = screnImagedata.data;

                var si = 0;
                for (var y=collMonInfos[i].y; y<collMonInfos[i].y+screenUseH; y++) {
                    for (var x=collMonInfos[i].x; x<collMonInfos[i].x+screenUseW; x++) {
                        var pix1 = (fullWidth*y*4) + (x * 4);
                        var B = iref[pix1];
                        siref[si] = iref[pix1+2];
                        siref[si+1] = iref[pix1+1];
                        siref[si+2] = B;
                        siref[si+3] = 255;
                        si += 4;
                    }
                }
                collMonInfos[i].screenshot = screnImagedata;
            }
            console.timeEnd('portion out image data');
```